# Hard drive shows 0 MB and fails to boot, but works after booting from a live CD and rebooting

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, linux-mint

I have an Asus K70AB laptop. Since 2 days ago something strange has occured. My hard drive is not recognized correctly by BIOS (size 0Mb) and therefore is not booting. But if I boot from a Linux Mint live CD and then restart my laptop does boot from hard drive (on both Linux Mint and Windows).

Anyone have any idea if its a faulty hard drive or a faulty mainboard? I need to know before purchasing a new hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect its a harddrive failure, that makes the drive take longer for itself to "boot itself up" and make itself available for the BIOS. By booting into the Linux live CD, you give the harddrive enough time for itself to "boot up". This, along with the 0 MB size detection, could indicate a high "Spinup Retry Count" on the disk, eg the motor or bearings on the drive is about to fail.

I would suggest you download this tool:
http://sourceforge.jp/projects/crystaldiskinfo/downloads/58588/CrystalDiskInfo5_6_2.zip/

from the booted windows partition, extract it, and then run DiskInfo.exe. If anything is YELLOW or RED, it means you should replace that disk ASAP, then its literally broken and were talking about even hours (and not days) Before it breaks completely leading to data loss. I would then suggest replacing it with an SSD since SSDs are more reliable than physical HDDs.

However, there COULD be your motherboard aswell, for example BIOS bugs and such. So if CrystalDiskInfo says "Good" on your harddrive, then try downloading a BIOS update from your mobo's or computer manufacturer's website, and update.